# Dual Boot: Cannot boot into Ubuntu after Windows 10 Creator's Update

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

Yesterday I installed the Win 10 Creator's update and can no longer see the Ubuntu select OS screen on start-up. I couldn't find the solution anywhere. I'll be grateful if someone can help.
Thanks

Comment: If UEFI all you need to do is select Ubuntu as first priority again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open Ubuntu by using USB stick and run Boot-Repair. You can temporarily install it even if you use USB stick.

From the Ubuntu wiki page on [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair):

> ### 1st option : get a disk including Boot-Repair
>
> The easiest way to use Boot-Repair is to create a disk containing the
>   tool (eg [Boot-Repair-Disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home), a disk starting Boot-Repair
>   automatically), and boot on it.
>
> Remark : it is recommended to install the ISO on a [live-USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) (eg
>   via [UnetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) or [LiliUSB](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) or [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)).
>   Do not burn it on a DVD if your computer has Windows8 pre-installed,
>   or if your boot is in [EFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) mode.
>
> ### 2nd option : install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu
>
> - either from an Ubuntu live-session ([boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD) then choose "Try Ubuntu") or from your
>     installed Ubuntu session (if you can access it)
> - connect to the Internet
> - open a new [Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Terminal), then type the following commands (press Enter after each line):
>
>   ```
>   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
>   ```
>
> ### Recommended repair
>
> 1. launch Boot-Repair from either :
>
>    1. the Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen)
>    2. or by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal
> 2. Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (**paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX**) that appeared on a
>      paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.
> 3. If the repair did not succeed, indicate the URL to people who help you by email or forum.

Comment: If you copy a block of text from somewhere, please put it in a blockquote to show that you're quoting it. See my edit for how to do this.