# I can't boot into Ubuntu after the Windows10 Creator's Update. It always boots into Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

First of all I followed the advice given in the links:

[Dual Boot: Cannot boot into Ubuntu after Windows 10 Creator's Update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905365/dual-boot-cannot-boot-into-ubuntu-after-windows-10-creators-update)

Just like they asked I repaired the grub using an ubuntu live disk  and boot repair. And I uploaded the log to https://www.paste2.org/dlbCkaDc

And for some weird reason it got deleted.

[image]

If I reinstalled Ubuntu, that would technically repair the boot right?

UPDATE: Reinstalling 17.04 doesn't work, it still loads into Windows.

Comment: Are you saying that it doesn't even give you a choice to boot Ubuntu?

Comment: When I select the ubuntu partition in the boot order it still boots into Windows. I followed the instructions in the above comment and now managed to get inside but now the boot process is so long and everytime I have to press F12 and select the relevent option for ubuntu. Now there are three options. One ubuntu and two windows. I can log in into ubuntu If I clicked the second windows one in the bios boot order menu.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/8Ibi2

Comment: @prab4th Try going into your UEFI settings and changing the boot order so that Ubuntu is on top.

Comment: That's what I tried first. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: This is the new paste from the laste boot-repair: https://pastebin.com/NKaW22tj still the same error.

Comment: L know this was marked duplicate, but I tried every solution given in the question but still can't have grub to load by default. It would be a great help if someone can help. If you need more info I can put them here

Comment: OK, I looked at your boot-repair log. The output from `efibootmgr -v` indicates your boot order goes "USB, Windows, Grub (created in Windows), Grub (created in Linux), DVD, Network". So please double-check the boot order in UEFI settings. Where reinstalling Ubuntu has had no effect, it would make sense that this is the issue. Although FWIW, I'm no expert on booting.

Comment: Hey it worked! The problem so far has been both Grub (created in Windows) and Grub (created in Linux) had the same name in bios so I was confused. Thanks